# Setting param to be the same as current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a webapp with Rails. I have a master user and the user has_many students that belong to them. The user can create new students when they are logged in. I want the students they create to have a param :teacher_id set to the current user's id. I have tried several different things. Here is my current relevant code:

students_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @student = Student.new(student_params)
  if @student.save
      redirect_to '/pages/tlanding'
    else
  redirect_to '/pages/newaccount'
end
end
```

and in the file where the user accesses the ability to edit their students:

```
<%= form_for Student.new do |f| %>
firstname:<%= f.text_field :name %> <br/>
username:<%= f.text_field :username %> <br>
password:<%= f.text_field :password %> <br>
<%= f.hidden_field :teacher_id, :value => @current_user.id %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My users log in before they can see this page and I am utilizing a sessions controller as well. However, when I create a new user, it returns teacher_id as nil. What can I do to make it return the user_id of the current user? (I am new to Rails and doing this to learn. I did not use Devise to set any of this up.)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you permitting `teacher_id` in `student_params`?

Comment: I actually wasn't, but when I added it, it still returned nil.

Comment: Well, what if you inspect "raw" `params`, what's in there? maybe your `@current_user.id` _does_ evaluate to nil?

Comment: Yes, I inspected @current_user and their ID is there. It's just not being set to the student's teacher_id.

Comment: I actually just got it working, I had the wrong foreign key in my student model. I appreciate your help, though, I wouldn't have gotten it working without you reminding me to include the params! Thank you!

Comment: It's a bad practice to set the current_user's id as a hidden field, you already have the current_user, if you use a hidden field it can be changed manually before submission. Just do `@student.teacher = current_user` (or, more elegant, `@student = current_user.students.build(students_params)`) on your action before saving the student.

Comment: @student.teacher_id = current_user returns nil